# Perl で `Use of uninitialized value concatenation` を出さないイディオムはありませんか?

Tags: perl

Perl で文字列を生成するとき、よく `Use of uninitialized value concatenation` を出してしまうので、どうにか解消したいと考えています。

これは初期化されていない(というか、undef が入っている)変数を文字列として結合したときに出ますが、毎回必ず初期値を入れるのはコード量が多くなるので嬉しくありません。

undef の場合に、空白になるようなイディオムはないのでしょうか?

例えば Ruby だと、変数が nil のとき、`+` で文字列結合しようとするとエラーになりますが、
式展開するとエラーになりません。
( `nil.to_s => ''` になるので )

```
irb(main):005:0> a = nil
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> a + "bbb"
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
        from (irb):6
        from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):007:0> "#{a}bbb"
=> "bbb"
```

よって、Ruby では「文字列を生成するときは、必ず式展開を使う」というルールにしてしまえば、この系統のエラーは防げます。

一方、Perl では、文字列結合でも、変数展開でも、エラーはでませんが、どちらでも warning が出ます。

```
24> $b = undef
$res[18] = undef

25> $b . "222"
Use of uninitialized value $b in concatenation (.) or string at reply input line 1.
$res[19] = '222'

31> "${b}222"
Use of uninitialized value $b in concatenation (.) or string at reply input line 1.
$res[22] = '222'
```

この warning を出さないようにするには、どう書くのが良いでしょうか。

`追記 2016-10-18`

提示した例が、意図を説明できない例だったので、追記します。
(変数を宣言するときに初期値を入れるのは、当然ですよね……)

(id と 名前) のハッシュと、(id と 年齢) のハッシュ、があるとき、それを合成して表示することを考えます。
但し、年齢があるとは限りません。

```
21> my $ids_names = { 10 => '佐藤一郎',  20 => '鈴木二郎',  30 => '田中三郎' }
$res[15] = {
  '10' => '佐藤一郎',
  '20' => '鈴木二郎',
  '30' => '田中三郎'
}

22> my $ids_ages = { 10 => 40, 30 => 20 };
$res[16] = {
  '10' => 40,
  '30' => 20
}

32> map { $ids_names->{$_} . " (" . $ids_ages->{$_} . ") さん" } keys %$ids_names;
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at reply input line 1.
$res[21] = [
  '鈴木二郎 () さん',
  '田中三郎 (20) さん',
  '佐藤一郎 (40) さん'
]
```

このとき、`Use of uninitialized value in concatenation` を避けるイディオムは、ないでしょうか?

ruby は、エラーになりませんし、

```
irb(main):001:0> ids_names = { 10 => '佐藤一郎',  20 => '鈴木二郎',  30 => '田中三郎' }
=> {10=>"佐藤一郎", 20=>"鈴木二郎", 30=>"田中三郎"}
irb(main):002:0> ids_ages = { 10 => 40, 30 => 20 }
=> {10=>40, 30=>20}
irb(main):008:0> ids_names.map { |id, name| "#{name} (#{ids_ages[id]}) さん" }
=> ["佐藤一郎 (40) さん", "鈴木二郎 () さん", "田中三郎 (20) さん"]
```

python は get で初期値が使えます。

```
In [1]: ids_names = {10: '佐藤一郎',  20: '鈴木二郎',  30: '田中三郎' }
In [2]: ids_ages = { 10: 40, 30: 20 }
In [7]: ["{} ({}) さん".format(name, ids_ages.get(id, '')) for (id, name) in ids_names.items()]
Out[7]: ['佐藤一郎 (40) さん', '鈴木二郎 () さん', '田中三郎 (20) さん']
```

perl も python に習って、

```
32> map { $ids_names->{$_} . " (" . ($ids_ages->{$_} // '') . ") さん" } keys %$ids_names;
```

のように書くのか、もっと良いイディオムがあるのか、知りたいと考えています。
(それなりに頻出だと思うのですが……)

Comment: 初期値は入れたくないとのことですが、一般的には変数は明示的に初期化した方が良いとされていますよね。それが嬉しくないなら@metropolisさんの言うようそもそも警告を抑制しようということになってしまいます。メンテ不能なコードになりそうです。`$b ||= ""`でセットするか、`($b || "")` とするか `(defined $b) ? $b : ""`とするか。余計読みづらそうですが...。

Answer (score 1):

イディオムではないのですが、`Tie::Hash` を使う方法などを。

`FETCH` メソッドをオーバーライドしてデフォルト値(ここでは空文字列)を返すようにしています。

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package DefaultHash;

use Tie::Hash;
use base qw(Tie::StdHash);

sub FETCH {
  my ($self, $key) = @_;
  return exists $self->{$key} ? $self->{$key} : ''
}

package main;

use Data::Dumper;

my $ids_names = { 10 => '佐藤一郎',  20 => '鈴木二郎',  30 => '田中三郎' };

tie my %ids_ages_hash, 'DefaultHash';
%ids_ages_hash = ( 10 => 40, 30 => 20 );
my $ids_ages = \%ids_ages_hash;

print Dumper map { $ids_names->{$_} . " (" . $ids_ages->{$_} . ") さん" } keys %$ids_names;
```

Answer (score 0):

特定のスコープだけ対象の警告を抑制すればよいのではないですか？

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $ids_names = +{
    10 => '佐藤一郎',
    20 => '鈴木二郎',
    30 => '田中三郎',
};

my $ids_ages = +{
    10 => 40,
    30 => 20,
};

print Dumper map {
    no warnings 'uninitialized';
    sprintf '%s (%s) さん', $ids_names->{$_}, $ids_ages->{$_};
} sort keys %{$ids_names};
```

もしくはno warningsを使わずundefを空文字列で扱いたい意図を明確にするなら、`sprintf`の第二引数以降をmapに食わせればいいと思います。

```
print Dumper map {
    sprintf '%s (%s) さん',
        map { $_ // q{} } $ids_names->{$_}, $ids_ages->{$_};
} sort keys %{$ids_names};
```